# JAXB ignores inner elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I've been trying to unmarshall a self-created xml configuration file to an object with JAXB default implementation, I ignore why, but some inner elements and values are skipped giving me null results.

Here is the xml document :

```
<import-sources>
    <domain-objects>
        <domain-object class="xxx.xxx.core.business.mapping.Make">
            <sources>
                <source name="xxxxxx" class="xxx.xxx.core.web.common.model.xxxxxxx.output.MakeDTO">
                    <uri secured="true" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
                    <key name="api_key" mode="in_uri" value="xxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
                </source>
            </sources>
    </domain-object>
</domain-objects>
```

this is the mapped class :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "import-sources")
public class ImportSources {

    @XmlType
    public static class DomainObject {

        @XmlType
        public static class Source {

            @XmlType
            public static class URI {

                private String value;

                private boolean secured;
            }

            @XmlType
            public static class Key {

                @XmlEnum
                public enum Mode {
                    @XmlEnumValue("in_uri")
                    IN_URI,
                    @XmlEnumValue("in_header")
                    IN_HEADER
                }

                private String name;

                private String value;

                private Mode mode;
            }


            private String name;


            private URI uri;


            private Key key;

            @XmlElement(name = "class")
            private Class outputClass;
        }

        @XmlAttribute(name = "class")
        private Class<? extends Entity> subjectClass;

        @XmlElementWrapper
        @XmlElement(name = "source")
        private Source[] sources;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "domain-objects")
    @XmlElement(name = "domain-object")
    private DomainObject[] domainObjects;
}
```

After parsing the document with Unmarshaller.unmarshall() all Source's fields are null, I can get its scalar fields if I replace its inner tag properties like so :

```
<source>
     <name>....</name>
     <class>...</class>
</source>
```

Which I want to avoid because of the redundancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally resolved my problem by annotating all fields I want within opening tags or single tags with '@XmlAttribute'.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to explicitly annotate fields as `@XmlElement` or `@XmlAttribute` correspondingly. Your class will look like the following then, and fields will get populated:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "import-sources")
public class ImportSources {

    @XmlType
    public static class DomainObject {

        @XmlType
        public static class Source {

            @XmlType
            public static class URI {


                @XmlAttribute //here
                private String value;

                @XmlAttribute //here
                private boolean secured;
            }

            @XmlType
            public static class Key {

                @XmlEnum
                public enum Mode {
                    @XmlEnumValue("in_uri")
                    IN_URI,
                    @XmlEnumValue("in_header")
                    IN_HEADER
                }

                @XmlAttribute //here
                private String name;

                @XmlAttribute //here
                private String value;

                @XmlAttribute //here
                private Mode mode;
            }


            @XmlAttribute //here
            private String name;

            @XmlElement //here
            private URI uri;

            @XmlElement //here
            private Key key;

            @XmlElement(name = "class")
            private Class outputClass;
        }

        @XmlAttribute(name = "class")
        private Class<? extends Entity> subjectClass;

        @XmlElementWrapper
        @XmlElement(name = "source")
        private Source[] sources;
    }
}
```